# tryToPerform:with: not being called when keyDown: is being called

Tags: cocoa, first-responder, responder-chain

I have a `NSViewController` which I manually put into the responder-chain by calling

```
self.nextResponder = self.view.nextResponder;
self.view.nextResponder = self;
```

When the user presses keys inside the view, I am able to successfully receive `keyDown:` messages. However, for some reason I'm not receiving `tryToPerform:with:` and `validateMenuItem:` messages when the user access the MainMenu bar. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that actually a `respondsToSelector:` message is being sent first before the `validateMenuItem:` is being called. And if the `NSViewController` doesn't actually respond to the message, the `validateMenuItem` never quite gets called. That said, in the whole process I never saw `tryToPerform:with:` getting called at all. Not sure why, going to look into Cocoa's Event Programming guide and report back.